# How to fix empty image in facebook share popup window

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

I'm trying to Share image to facebook using facebook-SDK, But the popup windows that appear don't show the image that i'm trying to share.

I have tried this jquery script:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
                'og:url': 'https://www.nuptial.me/album-content?d=1',
                'og:title': 'Any Title',
                'og:description': 'Any Description',
                'og:image:width': '461',
                'image:height': '369',
                'og:image' : 'https://images.nuptial.me/WedsiteImages/PreWedding1/Ahmad-Zeina-Pre-Ceremony-pictures-1805525916T1549016723.jpg',
                'og:image:type': 'image/jpeg'
            }
        })
    }, function (response) {

        if ($.isEmptyObject(response)) {

            // do something
        }
        });
```

What i was expected that the image should be share, but the popup windows that appear don't show the image.

(Please check this image)

[image: What popup is showing]https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqHU2.png

Thank you

Comment: why not just add the og:image to the source of the shared url? that´s the proper way. what you are trying to do right now is a workaround that may (hopefully) stop working sooner or later.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have to do it like this because this image should be share from a gallery page, thats why im using this method.

Comment: you really dont have to do it like this, just use a unique url for each image

Comment: Please can you send me an example ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/ - not sure what example you need, you only need to make sure that every picture has a unique url. and that url contains the correct og:image tag.